# Programmatically launch bash shell command 'osascript' using java

Tags: java, macos, osascript

I've tried with:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("osascript script.scpt");
pb.inheritIO();
pb.directory(new File("bin"));
try {
    pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I always get the error "no such file or directory".
I've tried also with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osascript script.scpt");
```

but nothing happens.

I also tried using this string in both the snippets above, but nothing changed.

```
osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\" to quit'
```

Comment: You should use `ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("osascript", "script.scpt");`

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593849/java-execute-process-on-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-ProcessBuilder-and-Runtime.exec . Note you are not running a bash command; `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` runs a program in a fashion similar in _some_ respects to a shell (including bash) command but not identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using this

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("osascript", "script.scpt");
```

This is because there's no tokenisation: the command to run is assumed to have already been tokenised.